# getBBox of SVG text after CSS has been applied

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I use JavaScript to add a text element to a SVG. And I have styled the text element with the following CSS:

```css
text {
    font: normal 15px sans-serif;
    fill: black;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
```

I have the following two lines in my code, which log the actual text of the text element (`txt`), the connect status of the text element (`label.isConnected`) and the bounding box of the text element (`label.getBBox()`):

```js
console.log (txt, label.isConnected, label.getBBox());
setTimeout (function () {console.log (txt, label.isConnected, label.getBBox())}, 1000);
```

The console output it the following:

```
Text true SVGRect { x: 0, y: 14, width: 28.08333396911621, height: 21 }
Text true SVGRect { x: -15.175000190734863, y: 16, width: 30.350000381469727, height: 18 }
```

It seems to me that the CSS decoration changes the position and the size of the bounding box. But I do not know when this is happening. And of course it is no option to wait some random time.

How to get the bounding box of the text element after the modification of the CSS decoration has been applied?

Comment: When are you calling the first console.log in relation to when you add the text and styling to the svg?

Comment: What your question doesn't mention is that this is about loading a web component. You are loading an external style sheet into your shadow tree. mozdev [explicitely warns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Internal_vs._external_styles) this is not happening synchronously. Unfortunately, moving the content of that callback to a `load` event callback for the stylesheet [does not work either](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events). I am out of ideas.

Comment: @ccprog Your hint is correct. The problem disappears, when I replace the link with internal styles.

Comment: What if you use the load Event on that stylesheet, with inside a ``setTimeout(Func,0)`` to delay execution/wait till the Event loop is done.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I am not sure but I think I tried to define the `onload` attribute of the `link` element and it did not have any effect. But even if it would be possible to define a hook after the CSS application has been done, it would not be very easy to use it. First I have to search all elements, which got changed by the CSS. And than I have to search all elements which depend on changed elements. And the depending elements have to be corrected. This is also not very efficient.

Comment: You say that setTimeout with ``1000`` milliseconds shows the correct values, then set it to ``0`` because all it does is wait for the Event Loop to be empty; which also means all repaints/reflows are done. Or I completely misunderstand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand what your problem is?

You want to execute getBBox after a repaint/reflow, forced by an async loaded CSS file, is done.

I used `onerror` instead of `onload` because the link to your CSS file is now a 404

If you call getBBox in a setTimeout (or rAF) doesn't the DOM have the correct state then?

```html
<template id=MY-ELEMENT>
  <style onload='log("template style loaded")'>
  </style>
</template>
<my-element></my-element>
<script>
  function log() { console.log(...arguments) }
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      log('constructor');
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'}).append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      log('template appended');
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      log('connectedCallback');
      let link = document.createElement('link');
      link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
      link.setAttribute('href', 'https://ceving.github.io/sociato/wf-graph.css');
      link.onerror = (evt) => {
        log('external CSS loaded');
        window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>log("rAF executed"));
        setTimeout(() => log('timeout after CSS load'))
      }
      this.shadowRoot.append(link);
      log('appended link');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I changed the CSS from external to internal. This is the commit, when the CSS was still external: https://github.com/ceving/sociato/tree/35c3396db11c363020f5ba4f53c690c6e83aac18